# The Child class constructor could not override the method which called within Parent Constructor in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have this constructor in my parent class.

```
 public function __construct()   
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setMasterVariant(new Variant());
    $this->taxons = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->variantSelectionMethod = self::VARIANT_SELECTION_CHOICE;
  }
```

i would like to change the param. here.

```
   $this->setMasterVariant(new Variant());
```

so with update here is my child class constructor

```
public function __construct()   
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setMasterVariant(new VariantNew());
    var_dump($this->getMasetVariant());
  }
```

As a result of

```
       var_dump($this->getMasetVariant());
```

I will get the result of Parent Class Instead of Sub Class.
So, can you Please me to sort out this issue?

Thank You.

Comment: Please post the `setMasterVariant` method.

Comment: public function setMasterVariant(VariantInterface $masterVariant)
    {
        if ($this->variants->contains($masterVariant)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $masterVariant->setProduct($this);
        $masterVariant->setMaster(true);

        $this->variants->add($masterVariant);

        return $this;
    }

you will find complete implementation of class on this link.

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/VariableProductBundle/Model/VariableProduct.php